# V-Select Readonly Bug

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, readonly, v-select

I am using Vue.js as a frontend framework and Vuetify framework.

I have a page where the users view the document. And all the fields are readonly.

There's an "edit" button which upon clicking it, removes the readonly props.

But upon removing the readonly in a v-select, the options are not popping out but the v-text-field can be edited.

Is there any other way on how to remove the readonly props in VueJS/Vuetify upon button click?

Comment: According to the vuetify documentation, v-select component have a readonly prop (type boolean), so you can switch it by binding it (<v-select :readonly="false" .........),  you can also use 'disabled' prop it'll give the same aspect.
check API documentation for more details : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-readonly

Comment: share some code of what you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code in your component. At first I have a button that specify edit mode with a click method and a v-select input with a boolean readonly prop.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
    editMode: false,
  }),
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-btn @click="() => editMode = !editMode" :color="editMode ? 'error' : 'success'">
        <v-icon left>
          {{editMode ? "mdi-close" : "mdi-pencil"}}
        </v-icon>
        {{editMode ? "Close" : "Edit"}}
      </v-btn>

      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-select :items="items" :readonly="!editMode" label="Read-only"></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```